# how to join three tables in oracle Sql Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Table 1 : TOY_STORE

```
      column names :Toy_store_id, Toy_store_name,city
```

Table 2 : TOY_DTLS

```
      column names :Toy_Id,Toy_name,toy_price,toy_rating
```

Table 3: Toy_rel

```
     column names : toy_id,toy_store_id,qty
```

How to display all Toy store names and Toy names?

Comment: On SO it is OK to post your homework, but only if you show what you tried and explain what worked, what didn't work, what you found confusing or surprising, etc. This is not a "do my homework for me" service.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some sample data and code, and tell us what isn't working for you. Also, check this link out: stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: you need a little headsup: pls see that http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp , and the next two chapters, and you can solve it

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT store.Toy_Store_name
,      toy.Toy_name
,      rel.qty
FROM   toy_rel    rel
JOIN   toy_dtls   toy     ON     rel.toy_id = toy.toy_id
JOIN   toy_store  store   ON     rel.toy_store_id = store.toy_store_id
;
```